# Multiple field in text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have an XML documents which include 3 titles.

```
<page> 
      <title>
      <title>
      <title>
```

Now I want to show them in one text field. I do the following

```
$F(title)+","+$F(title2)+","+$F(title3)
```

and it works well. There is a problem if title2 and title3 will be empty. assume if title2 is  empty in XML than the result is being like blow:I

```
This is the title 1 ,,This is title 3
```

is there suggestion for this?

Comment: Conditional expressions using ? : would be a way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

($F{title} != null ? $F{title} : "" ) 
+ ($F{title2} != null ? ", " + $F{title2} : "") 
+ ($F{title3} != null ? ", " + $F{title3} : "")

This is assumes that:
a) empty means null
b) field $F{title} will never be null

If I am wrong on assumption (b) this the expression gets only a little more complex. It can be done.